# Swift compile error: 'case' label can only appear inside a 'switch' statement?

Tags: swift, swift3, enums, swift4, enumeration

I have a simple code like:

```
enum Coin {
    case heads: 0
    case tails
}
```

It throws an error on Line 2 that

> error: 'case' label can only appear inside a 'switch' statement

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops that was simple & I found the answer

First I did:

```
enum Coin {
    case heads = 0
    case tails
}
```

Just changed `:` to `=` but it threw error

> Enum case cannot have a raw value if the enum does not have a raw type

So then I specified the type like:

```
enum Coin: Int {
    case heads = 0
    case tails
}
```

And voila it works

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
enum Coin: Int {
    case heads = 0
    case tails
}
```

Comment: Yes I got the answer as soon as I posted  but no other StackOverflow question had the error before. Also, Google didn't work either. Thank you :)